# I want to Export some table to Access using VB.NET

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a micro-finance software. A module 'special savings' i added with the software but before that the client did it manually (There was no software posting). So i like to develop a conversion tool to take the previous manual entry. But all member information and organization information in previous SQL db, where i develop the tool in Access DB. So i need to import some data with same table name to Access from SQL. I want to do the importing against a button instead of any wizard. So i want to export all data of my required tables including table name to my access file from SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same table schema available in Access DB, you can

1. read all data from Sql Server and write into Access tables.
2. Create a DTS package to do the export and call it when user clicks on "Data Import"

Answer (score 0):

Create a linked table in Access then use

```
INSERT INTO AccessTable (Column1, Column2, ...)
SELECT Column1,Column2,... FROM SqlServerTable
```